# react es6 project doesn't run on Safari & Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader, babel-polyfill

I am working on react/redux based project in which I am using Ecma Script 6 (ES6). The project runs successfully on Chrome & Firefox but NOT on Safari & Internet Explorer (IE).

I came to know when I opened the console of the Safari & IE. 
I have configured `babel` as well. I have a `babel.config.js` as below.

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)

  const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

  const presets = ['@babel/preset-react']
  const plugins = [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions',
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
    [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
      {
        corejs: 2,
        regenerator: false,
        useESModules: true,
      },
    ],
    'react-hot-loader/babel',
  ]

  if (isProd) {
    presets.push([
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false,
        loose: true,
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        exclude: ['transform-regenerator', 'transform-async-to-generator'],
      },
    ])
    plugins.push(
      [
        'module:fast-async',
        {
          compiler: {
            promises: true,
            generators: false,
          },
          runtimePattern: null,
          useRuntimeModule: false,
        },
      ],
      'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
    )
  } else {
    plugins.push('@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread')
  }

  return {
    presets,
    plugins,
  }
}
```

As, I came to know that Safari & IE throwing errors that `const` and `arrow functions` are not defined and have syntax error, I added below code for `arrow functions` in `babel.config.js`:

```
require('@babel/core').transform('code', {
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions'],
})
```

Below images shows Safari errors for reference.
[image: safari arrow function err]
[image: safari const err]

and Same goes for Internet Expolrer.

Can someone help me how to run my project on Safari & IE. 
Which plugin or polyfill need to be used to transform all the ES6 syntax to the browser needed syntax.

Waiting for replies & answers.

Thanks

Comment: Babel just transpiles the ES6 code into ES5 which is supported by all the browsers. As far as I know babel is sufficient for this and you don't need any other plugin or polyfill. I don't think the babel is working correctly in your case. You need to check  that.

Comment: I have all the necessary babel configuration, i think:
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.15",

Comment: Also check which versions of Safari and IE you are using. Try running code on latest versions of the browsers.

Comment: I am using IE 11 & Safari 5.1.7

Comment: You can try one thing use 'create react app' to create a test project and try same code there on same browsers. see if it works there. If it works then surely your babel configuration is an issue, else not

Comment: Have you imported babel-polyfill in the entry point of your app?

Comment: I have added polyfill (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) , still, it is not working

Comment: I have the same issue with babel 7 on IE11.  Iv tried the 3 different ways to use the `useBuiltIns` option with the `@babel/preset-env` and none of them work

Comment: I have also used the same `useBuiltIns ` with `usage` and all other values but none of them work